# Python OOM issue on Databricks after cleaning the list

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, databricks

We are extracting JSON data via Python, and the response contains quite heavy nested objects.
I added looping and batching for each request, and in every iteration, i clear the list (to avoid OOM issues), but still, after like 10 iterations I am getting OOM.
I also tried to create a spark action (every list result was transformed in DataFrame), to get a better distribution, but still, i am getting python OOM error even if the Python list is cleared in every iteration.
Steps:

1. Get JsonObjects in list
2. Create dataframe d1 from list
3. union d1 to masterDF
4. call d1.count() to invoke spark
5. clear list
6. repeat while we got results from response

> ```
> def get_heavy_data(date_from, date_to):
> rawDF = create_empty_df(columns)
> date_from_epoch = date_from.strftime("%s")
> date_to_epoch = date_to.strftime("%s")
> response_list = [1]
> batch_size = 1500
> iteration = 0
> while response_list:
>   print(f'taking {batch_size} skipping{batch_size*iteration}')
>   response_list.clear()
>   response_list = []
>   response_list = list(
>       session.query_collection("HeavyData").where_between(
>           "timestampField", date_from_epoch, date_to_epoch
>       )
>       .take(batch_size)
>       .skip(batch_size*iteration)
>     )
>   print(f'total retrieved objects for iteration {iteration} is {len(response_list)}')
>   iteration += 1
>   rawDF = rawDF.union(convert_response_to_df(response_list, date_from))
>   print(f" total number of items in dataframe : {rawDF.count()}")
>   time.sleep(35)
> return rawDF
> ```

Is there a way to keep only data in dataframe and not to get Python OOM issue, as i am guessing data is somehow persisted within the python list or memory cache.

The idea is to distribute data once dataframe is created and merged to main DF, and ideally only one iteration should be saved within the list.

Looking forward for any feedback on this topic.